# Custom map-reduce input formatter for Cassandra using native protocol

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using Apache Cassandra (1.2) and Apache Map-Reduce to crunch some data. At the moment I use `CqlPagingInputFormat` from *org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3*. This provider uses Thrift to pull  data. It seems that Thrift is fairly slow (300M records, in a 3 node cluster takes 8+ hours to read), and since a native binary protocol exist, I wonder if anyone has used it.

I am not interested in any other optimization and configuration tweaks - that's a separate issue.

My questions are

1. Is there an implementation of a map-reduce input formatter that directly use Cassandra native protocol?
2. If not, what would be the first steps to write my own, for example using a DataStax driver?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra 2.0.7 includes native protocol analogs for the CQL Hadoop classes:

org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlInputFormat 
org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordReader
org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlConfigHelper

The WordCount code in examples/hadoop_cql3_word_count has been updated to use these classes.

The JIRA that introduced this is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6311

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. However, I need to read from wide rows using pagination. And the `CqlPagingInputFormat` and `CqlPagingRecordReader` are still using Thrift, so writing my own implementation atm. Not sure why this issue is marked as resolved, it's not. Thanks for the answer though. I am surprised this hasn't been done years ago.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, if your data is in "old style" thrift wide rows, which you manually page through with slices then you'd use ColumnFamilyInputFormat. If your data is in CQL3 tables, then you aren't interacting directly with the wide rows, as C* is abstracting that away behind the CQL table structure

Comment: Good point, I probably didn't understand what I was saying. I'll give it a shot now.